# Forward all traffic into an HTTPS node server to another node process in a way that the other process can respond directly to the client?

Tags: node.js, https, redirect

I just finished working on a webapp of mine that will have lots of quick interactions between a client and the server over HTTP. I was just in the process of setting up a node https server/listener to deal with logins/registrations over SSL, when I realized that I have a problem. My http server (also node, just not https) is where all the magic in my software happens, and for speed reasons this cannot be https. It uses a sessioning system to keep track of the clients, and while in development, the logins were tested in http. Now that I'm trying to make the logins secure, the sessioning system will be broken, since logins will be arriving at a separate process.

I figure that it shouldn't be too difficult to simply have my https server redirect all the traffic coming into it to the http server. However, I'm not sure how to do this in a way such that when the http server does its thing and calls response.end(), the response is returned to the client that originally talked to the https server. Does anybody know how to do this?

Alternatively, does anybody more knowledgeable than me have any other suggestions? Maybe having the response returned to the https server and then forwarded back to the client?

Best, and thanks in advance for reading this far,
Sami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for message queuing technology like ZeroMQ. In particular, a web server like Mongrel2 which makes message queuing its core, would be a good thing to use.

Your problem might actually be solveable just by having the http server open up another window or iframe with the https server, and have the https server communicate to the http server on the backend once the client is authenticated. Since a single web server process could handle both http and http traffic, this could even be done inside the server using something as crude as PHP, but it is not scalable to pile on everything into one process on one server.

Once you start down the road of having multiple servers at the backend, each doing a part of the job, it is a good idea to start working with a communications technology that is both flexible and scalable. That is what you get with ZeroMQ and Mongrel2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for an HTTPS proxy then you should use nginx or stud in front of haproxy to do it, rather than node -> node.